# Excel formula grammar in BNF or any other notations

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, formula, bnf

I am looking for a grammar of Excel formulas in BNF or another notation. We need to parse the input formula with JavaScript to check its validity and the actual formula evaluation will then take place on the server side.

Comment: Why do you need it? Isn't it sufficient that the server does the validation?

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your comments. We are trying to get the excel spreadsheet in the web browser. We need a way to get the cell references highlighted on the fly when we enter/select the cell, ranges etc. After going through the concepts behind this, we need a way to define the grammar for excel formulas and need to parse the formulas for getting cell references, coloring the cells, identifying the functions etc. To give you more clarity on this, just look at the google docs spreadsheet functionality which we are trying to implement the it.

Answer (score 4):

[MS-XLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd908135%28v=office.12%29.aspx) has a free-form grammar (tries to be an EBNF but is far from formal)

More hints are available in [MS-OE376](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff533995%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and section L.2.16 of ECMA-376.

But to answer your question, there is no official BNF

Answer (score 1):

Section 2.2.2 (page 32) of the [[MS-XLSX]: Excel (.xlsx) Extensions to the Office Open XML SpreadsheetML File Format](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSX/%5bMS-XLSX%5d.pdf) has a useful grammar describing Excel formulas. [Other versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-xlsx/2c5dee00-eff2-4b22-92b6-0738acd4475e) of the specification are also available.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a site where the author parses Excel formulas in javascript.  There are other versions of his parser available.

http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2004/12/excel_formula_p.html